# Java:Clarifications in Java Interview Questions

Tags: java, comparator

I recently attended the Java Interview Questions and had the below queries for which i dont know the answers

1> I have below class

```
 class CricketTeam{             
   String name; //this is the complete name(inclusive of first and last name)          
 }
```

Cricket Players name are as below:

`1> Sachin Tendulkar`
`2> Gautam Gambhir`
`3> Ricky Ponting`
`4> Shahid Afridi`
`5> Kevin Pieterson`
`6> MS Dhoni`

I want to sort the above Cricket Players name by their `last name only`.Suugestions/code provided would be appreciated.

2> what are the advantages of using `enhanced for loop` against
`iterator` in java.what are the advantages of using enhanced for loop in java and why was it introduced in java at the first place when the `iterator` could do the job.?

Comment: Are the cricket players in a list or an array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. implement a `Comparator` which parses the last name out of player names and compares these, then sort the collection of cricket players using that comparator.
   A simplistic example (without error handling, and assuming all players have exactly one first name and no middle name):

   ```
   class CricketTeamComparator implements Comparator<CricketTeam> {
       @Override
       public int compare(CricketTeam o1, CricketTeam o2) {
           String lastName1 = o1.name.split(" ")[1];
           String lastName2 = o2.name.split(" ")[1];
           return lastName1.compareTo(lastName2);
       }
   }

   ...

   List<CricketTeam> team = new ArrayList<CricketTeam>();
   ...
   Collections.sort(team, new CricketTeamComparator());
   ```
2. it is cleaner, more concise and safer (e.g. avoids specific subtle bugs in multiple embedded loops, when the iterator is accidentally incremented too often by calling `next()` too many times).
   Code sample (from [Effective Java 2nd Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), Item 46: *Prefer for-each loops to traditional for loops*):

   ```
   // Can you spot the bug?
   enum Suit { CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART, SPADE }
   enum Rank { ACE, DEUCE, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT,
   NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING }
   ...
   Collection<Suit> suits = Arrays.asList(Suit.values());
   Collection<Rank> ranks = Arrays.asList(Rank.values());
   List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
   for (Iterator<Suit> i = suits.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
     for (Iterator<Rank> j = ranks.iterator(); j.hasNext(); )
       deck.add(new Card(i.next(), j.next()));
   ```

Comment: Torok: String.split() actually works off regex strings, so a better way of implementing the split step is to use `split("\\s+")` instead of `split(" ")`. The `+` quatifier ensures that if the data is input with excess whitespace in between the first and last names you won't get `["First", "", "Last"]` in your split string array - which would break your comparator.

Comment: Or `splitted = split(" ")`, `lastName = splitted[splitted.length - 1]` if someone decides to insert a middle name...

Answer (score 2):

1.Check this sample code:

```
// assuming this is the list with cricket players
List<CricketTeam> team; 

Collections.sort(team, new Comparator<CricketTeam>) {
    int compare(CricketTeam o1, CricketTeam o2) {
        return o1.name.split(" ")[1].compareTo(o2.name.split(" ")[1])
    }
}
```

2.It is more readable, easier to use and hides unnecessary details.

Comment: can you give me a working example for 1st question

Comment: I just did:-). You just have to create `team` list and fill it with some sample values.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, can you split the `name` string based on the _ (space) delimiter and then sort based on the `name_arr[1]` array element? "Regroup" the array elements for reporting.

Here's a code example using a simple array. Since the requirement is to sort based on the last name, this splits the string based on the space delimiter, flips the resulting name, sorts the array, and then reforms by "re-flipping" (confused, yet? :)

```
public static String[] FlipAndSort (String[] name) {

        for (int i=0;i<name.length;i++) {
            String [] flip = name[i].split(" ");
            name[i]=flip[1]+" "+flip[0];
        }
        Arrays.sort(name);
        for (int i=0;i<name.length;i++) {
            String [] flip = name[i].split(" ");
            name[i]=flip[1]+" "+flip[0];
        }
        return name;
    }
```

For question 2, readability is my personal preference...

Comment: can you give me a working example for 1st question